# MySQL: sort list of values before use it in the query

Tags: mysql, sql, md5

Can I sort list of values before use it in the query?

Like `SELECT SORTINGFN(2,3,1)` and get `1,2,3`?
Something like `SELECT 2,3,1 ORDER BY ??? ASC`, but order by what?

I need to make sure the arguments are always in the same order, to get the same hash from `MD5('1,2,3')` and `MD5('2,3,1')`

Answer (score 1):

Without table(set values for `argx`):

```
SELECT arg1,arg2,arg3,
   MD5(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col ORDER BY col) 
       FROM (SELECT arg1 AS col
             UNION ALL SELECT arg2 
             UNION ALL SELECT arg3) AS sub) AS md5_checksum
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/41198/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦════╦════╦══════════════════════════════════╗
║ 1  ║ 2  ║ 3  ║           md5_checksum           ║
╠════╬════╬════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 2  ║ 3  ║ 55b84a9d317184fe61224bfb4a060fb0 ║
║ 3  ║ 2  ║ 1  ║ 55b84a9d317184fe61224bfb4a060fb0 ║
║ 3  ║ 1  ║ 2  ║ 55b84a9d317184fe61224bfb4a060fb0 ║
╚════╩════╩════╩══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Anyway `MD5` is weak hash algorithm.

---

SQL can do a lot. Question is it good place for such operation, when you could do it at application layer.

Arbitrary list:

```
SELECT MD5(GROUP_CONCAT(val ORDER BY val)) AS md5_sum
FROM (
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.results, ',', n.n), ',', -1) AS val
  FROM (SELECT '3,2,1,10,212,3123,1' AS results) AS t 
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
     SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
       FROM 
      (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
     ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
  ) n
  WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.results) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.results, ',', '')))
) sub
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/41206/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════╗
║        args          ║             md5_sum              ║
╠══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║ 3,2,1,10,212,3123,1  ║ e2003296ed64cb59be61558275e22433 ║
║ 212,3123,1,3,2,1,10  ║ e2003296ed64cb59be61558275e22433 ║
╚══════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: I need to sort IDs coming from application with MySQL. There is no table with that IDs, they are just arguments.
Yes, I can sort them in the application, but maybe it is possible with MySQL, just for curiosity.

Comment: interesting idea, but the IDs list has arbitrary length

Comment: @Kanstantsin And where is the problem? Just add more args `(SELECT arg1 AS col
             UNION ALL SELECT arg2 
             UNION ALL SELECT arg3 UNION ALL ...)`

Comment: Problem is that with this approach it's really easier to sort arguments with the scripting language

Comment: @Kanstantsin So do it :)